# p:fileUpload loads forever in IE9 after clicking upload button

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have below code. But does not know why in my computer IE9, it shows non stop loading when click upload button. But it works on chrome and firefox.

```
<p:fileUpload  id="fileUpload1s1"
               process="@form"
               label="Browse" 
               multiple="false"
               fileUploadListener="#{DataController.uploadataFile}"                                               
               mode="advanced"
               showButtons="false"
               auto="false"                                               
               sizeLimit="4000000"
               allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt)$/"
               required="true"> 
</p:fileUpload>
```

Comment: What's your PrimeFaces version? Is there any error being displayed on browser's console?

Comment: No error display. As to primefaces version, it is 5.0

Comment: checked compatibility mode? Checked a newer version of PF?

Comment: Until the latest version of PrimeFaces which is 5.3, everything goes fine on IE 8. IE 9 has more problems than IE 8. I personally do not care much, if something goes fishy on any versions before 10 (exclusive).

Answer (score 0):

I have create button to handle upload as below code in upload button action. have not used upload button inside the fileupload control.

```
function clickUpload() {
                var b = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId("form1:excelUpload")+" .ui-fileupload-preview").length;

                if(b==0)
                    edis.showErrorMsg("Please select an Text File to upload");
                else {
                    $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId("form1:excelUpload")+" .ui-fileupload-upload")[0].click();
                }
            }
```